# How to add a topbar menu item in elgg?

Tags: php, elgg

I'm simply trying to add an item to the topbar-default menu in elgg. I'm just learning PHP, and I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work. When I inspect the element with chrome, I am told that it its class is `elgg-menu elgg-menu-topbar elgg-menu-topbar-default`:

```
elgg_register_menu_item('topbar', array(
    'name'  => 'qanda',
    'href'  => '/answers/',
    'title' => 'Questions and Answers'),
));
```

I am using elggzone's dark theme.

After explaining all that, my question is simple. How do I add an item to this menu in elgg? I would like to use an image such as `elgg-icon elgg-icon-mail`

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your start.php

```
elgg_register_menu_item('topbar', array(
   'name'  => 'manu_name',
   'href'  => 'menu_link',
   'title' => 'menu_title',
   'text'  => elgg_view_icon('menuMail'),
 )
);
```

Now you need to add the corresponding css property for the class

```
.elgg-icon-menuMail{
   background: transparent url('path/to/an/image') no-repeat left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elgg_register_menu_item('topbar', array(
    'name'  => 'qanda',
    'href'  => '/answers/',
    'title' => 'Questions and Answers'),
    'item_class' => array('elgg-icon', 'elgg-icon-mail')
));
```